# Kafka force JKS re-load

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a kafka client which uses ssl.

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka1:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
```

**Circumstances:**
The jks files upgraded periodically,because they expire after a while.
So the JKS is up to date all the time on the filesystem.

But the kafka client still uses the old jks, because it only reads it when the client is created.

Expired JKS doesn't matter if:

- Is an ongoing session (because the handshake already happened at the beginning of the session)
- The client is restarted (it will pickup the new jks and do the handshake)

**The issue:**

When in the middle of a session kafka broker is down and come back to life, the handshake process starts over again **WITHOUT** reading the JKS from the file-system causing a handshake error.

This leads to an unreliable KafkaClient if SSL is in place.

What is the solution?
Is there anything like `ssl.keystore.forceread=true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder` provides `reconfigure` method, it appears to be used only by the Kafka broker code.

In case of clients, it looks like you'd need to restart them, as the ChannelBuilder instance is configured only once, at startup.

Reference (Kafka 2.8):

- [ChannelBuilders](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.8.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/network/ChannelBuilders.java#L192)
- [SSLChannelBuilder](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.8.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/network/SslChannelBuilder.java#L74)

Comment: And how to restart it?
Or how to stop the client in case of failure?
The exception comes from it's own network-thread. I coulnd't find a way to catch it and act accordingly.

Comment: A clunky solution would be to monitor metrics - it's possible some of them (like connection close rate) might indicate that something is wrong (but it might be caused by other factors, hence the clunkiness). Overall, it feels like your architecture needs some kind of orchestrator that notifies the applications that it's time to close and re-create Kafka clients because the certificate files have changed _everywhere_.

Comment: thanks, yeah the notification stuff will solve this I think.